# Using System.DirectoryServices in VBA

Tags: vba, active-directory, directoryservices

I am attempting to add a reference to System.DirectoryServices in my VBA application, but cannot seem to find the reference to add. Any help? I have a dll I used with my .NET C# app and I tried adding a copy it as a reference, but it was unable to add (I suspected it might not work, but worth a try). What reference is needed and where is it found for use of DirectoryServices in VBA?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is the "Active DS Type Library". The prefix is then `ActiveDs.`

*Note that this is not the .NET library.

Comment: Never used ActiveDS before. Know any good links I can use to research it? I'm going to do some googling myself, but it would make things easier if you knew of any. Does this use ADO to do the same thing as the .NET library?

Comment: I've never used it myself. A quick google search for "vb6 activeds" yielded this. http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=4935

Comment: Thanks. It looks promising.

Comment: Looks like that example uses late binding... Come to think of it, I've used this method before to return user names. It tends to be slow in my experience. Just FYI.